# Why doesn't Cobra see flags passed in CLI?

Tags: go-cobra

For some reason flags stopped working in my cobra app. It worked before and now the same code doesn't read flags on 2 different machines for me. Defined flags get only default values for some reason.

I reproduced it with following steps:

```bash
mkdir foo
cd foo
go mod init "example.com/foo"
cobra-cli init
```

Then I added example run func to my root command:

```golang
Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
    println("root command run")
},
```

and added `init` for flags in `./cmd/root.go`:

```golang
var flag bool
var status string

func init() {
    log.SetFlags(0)

    rootCmd.Flags().BoolVarP(&flag, "flag", "f", false, "Some bool flag")
    rootCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&status, "status", "s", "status_default", "Sets a status")

    log.Printf("status is '%v'", status)
    log.Printf("flag is '%v'", flag)

    log.Printf("Received args: %v", os.Args[1:])
}
```

then I build and run the app

```bash
go build
./foo -f --status=baz
```

and get the following output:

```
status is 'status_default'
flag is 'false'
Received args: [-f --status=baz]
root command run
```

Expected that flag would be `true` and status would be `baz`. Can't understand why this happens. The same method for getting flags is shown in [Cobra User Guide](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/main/site/content/user_guide.md). Other sources that I found online also use this approach. What did I do wrong?

### UPD Found the problem

Flags are not filled with values until command runs. So inside command run func I can read variables `status` and `flag` and they have values passed in CLI